# How can I filter rows where the first character of a column is in a range with EF and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,    
    [English]       NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL
)
```

Is there a way using Entity Framework that I can pick all those rows where the first character of the [English] column is less than "k". For example where it is either "a", "b", "c" ... "j" etc

Something like this:

```
query = query.Where(w =>   w.English.StartsWith("k");
```

but for the range of characters and not just for "k"

Comment: Try this: `query = query.Where(w =>   w.English.Substring(0,1) < "k"));`

Comment: @ZoharPeled - see comment below.  This will not work :-(

Comment: You can try `query = query.Where(w => w.English[0] < 'k');`. However, I'm not sure how it will handle case or non-alphabetic chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter this after fetching records from db. For this you can do the following:

```
var result = query.ToList();
```

And then filter it as follows:

```
result = result.Where(w => Convert.ToChar(w.English.Substring(0,1).ToLower()) < 'k');
```

In `SQL Server`, the following query would work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Substring(English, 1, 1) < 'k'
```

For range of characters, your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Substring(English, 1, 1) BETWEEB 'a' And 'j'
```

The above will fetch records on the condition that English column's first character should be in between of `a` and `j`. Please note that `a` and `j` will be inclusive in this case.

For only specific characters, your query would be:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE Substring(English, 1, 1) IN ('a', 'd', 'f')
```

The above will return those records whose english column starts with `a`, `d`, `f`. To negate you can use `NOT IN ('a', 'd', 'f')`

> I would suggest you to write a procedure with the above query and then
>   call it using entity framework. This approach would be much faster.

Comment: I get the message that < cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'